# How to make a const getter for an array which contains another class's instances?

Tags: c++, c++11, member-functions

The problem is the getter has to work on `const` `bar` objects. But the compiler says:

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'const foo*' to 'foo*' [-fpermissive]
```

The code:

```
class foo
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    foo()
    {
        name = "default";
    }
};

class bar
{
private:
    foo array_of_foo[43];
public:
    foo* get_array_of_foo() const { return array_of_foo; }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you **actually** need to obtain an array of mutable `foo`s from a constant `bar`? That sounds unlikely, and probably not what you actually want unless you are in the middle of a big, painful refactor.

Better alternatives would be:

```
// Return a mutable foo array from a mutable bar.
foo* get_array_of_foo() {return array_of_foo;}

// and/or

// Return a const foo array from a const bar.
const foo* get_array_of_foo() const {return array_of_foo;}
```

However, if you did paint yourself in a corner where you **really** need to do this, then you can use `const_cast<>` to get out of that jam.

```
foo* get_array_of_foo() const {return const_cast<foo*>(array_of_foo);}
```

That being said, it's a massive code smell, and a last resort.

Comment: It is a task for practrice at my university but I think it is a really big bullshit. They allways forcing us to make everything to const. :/

Comment: @PéterSchweitzer  Most things should be `const`.  That way, the important places where you actually have to update the data will be more obvious.  Recursively-enforced `const` is one of C++'s best features.

Comment: It only causes problems for me. :S I hate this language. Java is so much simpler.